How to upload and save images from keystone 6 to minio
i am trying to save photos from keystone 6 to minio,
my code :
enter image description here
errors:
An error occurred while resolving input fields.

Post.banner: boolean attribute 'crossorigin' is not allowed.:6:177
Deserialization error: to see the raw response, inspect the hidden field {error}.$response on this object.

enter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
